# How to set session attributes using RestAssured for Integration Tests

Tags: java, session, automation, integration-testing, rest-assured

I have a AbstractClass and this class has following code:

```
protected long getStudentIdFromSession() {
        Object obj = this.httpSession.getAttribute("studentId");
        Long formId = (obj instanceof Long ? (Long) obj : null);
        LOGGER.info("getStudentIdFromSession studentId {}", studentId);
        return formId;
}
```

I am writing an integration test to validate my rest end-points where the source code gets the studentId from the session.

So, I know we can add cookies as follows:

```
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie.Builder("studentId", studentId).setComment("setting studentId as cookie").build(); 
Cookies cookiesList = new Cookies(cookie1); 
Response authenticateResponse = 
        RestAssured.given().cookies(cookiesList).authentication().preemptive().basic("xyz", "xyz").get(AUTHENTICATED_USER_URL);
```

But this didn't serve my purpose, I need this attribute in the session.

Can someone help me to set the session attributes for my Integration Test using RestAssured ?

I am using library: "com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured"